# Why for closing parent window from an iframe, we need to call window.parent.window.close twice?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have encountered a situation in which, I need to close the parent window from an Iframe. I don't have the access to parent windows code, so I need to code in iframe code. So, I found calling window.parent.window.close twice, can close the parent window. But why it didn't work by calling it just one time?

Child/Iframe's body

```
<body>
    From children
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.parent.window.close();
            window.parent.window.close();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Parents Body

```
<body>
    From Parent
    <iframe src="./child.html">

    </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Console errors? I am surprised you even CAN close from the child

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: What error is YOU getting. I was asking.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. I am just curious that upon calling window.parent.window.close() twice, close the parent window,but not on calling single time. Why?

Comment: As I said, I am surprised you are even allowed to call it and that you succeed in closing it.

Comment: have you ever tried to run it?

Comment: No. I would have to load it onto my own site to test. Also I believe I only have half your script because you can only close a window from script that was opened by script on the sane domain. I do not have the code you use to open the window in the first place

Comment: You can create two html pages, name parent.html and child.html and put this html body tag in their respective files. And open the parent.html file in browser. There you can see the result

Comment: How do you open the first page

Answer (score 0):

First of as of latest spec.
Scripts can only close windows that are opened by them.
(i.e If you opened a window via window.open then only you can close it)
Or if the target window to be closed has only 1 document in the history context(i.e history == 1)

Calling window.close twice seems like a Chrome bug.
Try using Firefox
Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: I am surprised that, it is not working now in Chrome also. I didn't even update my browser. @RohanS404 you may be right, that earlier it is chromes bugs, that it was working.